# keep wistia overlay open on click - e.stopPropogation on outside box preventing it from closing - stopPropgation misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, overlay, stoppropagation

I have some overlays, one has a form and another has a video embed.

The form overlay stays open when you interact with it (I can't post the form because it's an embed and confidential) but the video one closes:

```js
// demo overlay
  let demoButton = document.querySelectorAll('.demo-link-button');
  let demoFormOverlay = document.getElementById('demo-overlay');
  let demoFormOverlayClose = document.getElementById('demo-overlay-close');
  let mainDemoOverlays = document.querySelectorAll('.main-overlay-box');

  // video overlay
  let demoOnDemandButton = document.querySelectorAll('.vid-overlay-trigger');
  let demoOnDemandFormOverlay = document.getElementById('demo-ondemand-overlay');
  let demoOnDemandFormOverlayClose = document.getElementById('demo-ondemand-overlay-close');
  
  
  demoButton.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'block';
    });
  });

  demoFormOverlayClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });

  demoOnDemandButton.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'block';
    });
  });

  // multiple overlays
  mainDemoOverlays.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
      demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
    });
  });
  demoOnDemandFormOverlayClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });
```

```css
.main-overlay-box {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 900;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 56%);
}
```

```html
<a class="demo-link-button" href="#">Open Overlay</a>
<a class="demo-link-button"  href="#">Open Overlay</a>
<a class="vid-overlay-trigger"  href="#">Open THE VIDEO Overlay</a>
<a class="vid-overlay-trigger"  href="#">Open THE VIDEO Overlay</a>

<div class="main-overlay-box" id="demo-overlay">
  <div class="demo-overlay-box">
    <a id="demo-overlay-close" href="#">X</a>
    <div style="background-color: #fff;">
      heres one overlay
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>

<div class="main-overlay-box" id="demo-ondemand-overlay">
  <div class="demo-overlay-box">
    <a id="demo-ondemand-overlay-close" href="#">X</a>
    <script src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/s3lqfi0zn7.jsonp" async></script>
<script src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_s3lqfi0zn7" style="height:349px;width:620px">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

When you click on "Open THE VIDEO Overlay" and try to play the video...it won't stay open.

The logic is here:

```
  mainDemoOverlays.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
      demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
    });
  });
```

I then figured out it was bubbling so I changed it to:

```js
// demo overlay
  let demoButton = document.querySelectorAll('.demo-link-button');
  let demoFormOverlay = document.getElementById('demo-overlay');
  let demoFormOverlayClose = document.getElementById('demo-overlay-close');
  let mainDemoOverlays = document.querySelectorAll('.main-overlay-box');

  // video overlay
  let demoOnDemandButton = document.querySelectorAll('.vid-overlay-trigger');
  let demoOnDemandFormOverlay = document.getElementById('demo-ondemand-overlay');
  let demoOnDemandFormOverlayClose = document.getElementById('demo-ondemand-overlay-close');
  
  demoButton.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'block';
    });
  });

  demoFormOverlayClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });

  demoOnDemandButton.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'block';
    });
  });

  // multiple overlays
  mainDemoOverlays.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropogation();
      demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
      demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
    });
  });
  demoOnDemandFormOverlayClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });
```

```css
.main-overlay-box {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 900;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 56%);
}
```

```html
<a class="demo-link-button" href="#">Open Overlay</a>
<a class="demo-link-button"  href="#">Open Overlay</a>
<a class="vid-overlay-trigger"  href="#">Open THE VIDEO Overlay</a>
<a class="vid-overlay-trigger"  href="#">Open THE VIDEO Overlay</a>

<div class="main-overlay-box" id="demo-overlay">
  <div class="demo-overlay-box">
    <a id="demo-overlay-close" href="#">X</a>
    <div style="background-color: #fff;">
      heres one overlay
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>

<div class="main-overlay-box" id="demo-ondemand-overlay">
  <div class="demo-overlay-box">
    <a id="demo-ondemand-overlay-close" href="#">X</a>
    <script src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/s3lqfi0zn7.jsonp" async></script>
<script src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_s3lqfi0zn7" style="height:349px;width:620px">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

But now, when I click on the transparent black area the modal doesn't close.

Why is that?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

> The stopPropagation() method of the Event interface prevents further
> propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.
> It does not, however, prevent any default behaviors from occurring;
> for instance, clicks on links are still processed. If you want to stop
> those behaviors, see the preventDefault() method. It also does not
> prevent immediate propagation to other event-handlers. If you want to
> stop those, see stopImmediatePropagation().

So I then tried

```js
// demo overlay
  let demoButton = document.querySelectorAll('.demo-link-button');
  let demoFormOverlay = document.getElementById('demo-overlay');
  let demoFormOverlayClose = document.getElementById('demo-overlay-close');
  let mainDemoOverlays = document.querySelectorAll('.main-overlay-box');

  // video overlay
  let demoOnDemandButton = document.querySelectorAll('.vid-overlay-trigger');
  let demoOnDemandFormOverlay = document.getElementById('demo-ondemand-overlay');
  let demoOnDemandFormOverlayClose = document.getElementById('demo-ondemand-overlay-close');
  
  demoButton.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'block';
    });
  });

  demoFormOverlayClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });

  demoOnDemandButton.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'block';
    });
  });

  // multiple overlays
  mainDemoOverlays.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
      demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
    });
  });
  demoOnDemandFormOverlayClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });
```

```css
.main-overlay-box {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 900;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 56%);
}
```

```html
<a class="demo-link-button" href="#">Open Overlay</a>
<a class="demo-link-button"  href="#">Open Overlay</a>
<a class="vid-overlay-trigger"  href="#">Open THE VIDEO Overlay</a>
<a class="vid-overlay-trigger"  href="#">Open THE VIDEO Overlay</a>

<div class="main-overlay-box" id="demo-overlay">
  <div class="demo-overlay-box">
    <a id="demo-overlay-close" href="#">X</a>
    <div style="background-color: #fff;">
      heres one overlay
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>

<div class="main-overlay-box" id="demo-ondemand-overlay">
  <div class="demo-overlay-box">
    <a id="demo-ondemand-overlay-close" href="#">X</a>
    <script src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/s3lqfi0zn7.jsonp" async></script>
<script src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_s3lqfi0zn7" style="height:349px;width:620px">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

But now we're right back to where we started.

How do you keep a wistia embed video open to play click, and keep the close button and clicking off of it functional? How does `stopPropogation()` work/how should it work in this context?

Or am I off and is `stopPropogation()` not the right concept here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, do you want this (so far only on the example of the video)?

```js
// demo overlay
let demoButton = document.querySelectorAll('.demo-link-button');
let demoFormOverlay = document.getElementById('demo-overlay');
let demoFormOverlayClose = document.getElementById('demo-overlay-close');
let mainDemoOverlays = document.querySelectorAll('.main-overlay-box');

// video overlay
let demoOnDemandButton = document.querySelectorAll('.vid-overlay-trigger');
let demoOnDemandFormOverlay = document.getElementById('demo-ondemand-overlay');
let demoOnDemandFormOverlayClose = document.getElementById('demo-ondemand-overlay-close');


demoButton.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'block';
  });
});

demoFormOverlayClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
});

demoOnDemandButton.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'block';
  });
});

// multiple overlays
mainDemoOverlays.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
    demoFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
demoOnDemandFormOverlayClose.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  demoOnDemandFormOverlay.style.display = 'none';
});

document.querySelector(".wistia_embed").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.main-overlay-box {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 56%);
}
```

```html
<a class="demo-link-button" href="#">Open Overlay</a>
<a class="demo-link-button" href="#">Open Overlay</a>
<a class="vid-overlay-trigger" href="#">Open THE VIDEO Overlay</a>
<a class="vid-overlay-trigger" href="#">Open THE VIDEO Overlay</a>

<div class="main-overlay-box" id="demo-overlay">
  <div class="demo-overlay-box">
    <a id="demo-overlay-close" href="#">X</a>
    <div style="background-color: #fff;">
      heres one overlay
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-overlay-box" id="demo-ondemand-overlay">
  <div class="demo-overlay-box">
    <a id="demo-ondemand-overlay-close" href="#">X</a>
    <script src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/s3lqfi0zn7.jsonp" async></script>
    <script src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
    <div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_s3lqfi0zn7" style="height:349px;width:620px">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```